# magento cloud, pause the cron job?

Tags: magento2, cron

I am using the Magento Cloud, is there anyway to pause or temporary disable the cron job running on Magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `'cron' =>['enabled' => 0],` to app/etc/env.php to temporary disable the cron job

Comment: since I am in Magento cloud, I may not able to modify this file. I will ask support to see what I can do, thank for your feedback, I am sure it should work

Comment: See: https://github.com/magento/ece-tools/issues/688#issuecomment-590200074

Answer (score 9):

1. Use SSH to log in to your environment.
2. Disable cron jobs and stop active cron processes.

```
./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:disable
```

3. After you complete any required maintenance tasks, ensure that you enable the cron jobs again.

```
./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:enable
```

Comment: Don't be suprised if you don't have this command available. It's only available on recent versions of ece-tools.